# How to use INDIRECT with a SUMIF formula for a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to get a SUMIFS formula to dynamically work with multiple tabs in an excel workbook.  I have numerous tabs in this workbook, each that contains client data I update daily.  In the example below I have a client called "Joes 27" and on that sheet there is sales data listed daily.  I am looking to have a summary page where I can enter a date range and have it sum up the sales data for that range for Joes 27.  And then for me to be able to switch it to another client name.  I use this currently:

`=SUMIFS('Joes 27'!5:5, 'Joes 27'!2:2, ">="&B1, 'Joes 27'!2:2, "<="&C1)`

"Joes 27" is the tab name of the client tab.  Others are called "Citi 15" for example.
Row 5 in each client tab is what I want added up.
Row 2 in each client tab is the list of dates. (6/1, 6/2 , 6/3)
On the summary page, I enter the date range in `B1` and `C1` (6/1   6/3)

What formula can I use so I can enter a client name on the summary page and have it use the SUMIFS formula to add up the data in that range on that page.  I assume INDIRECT function but I can't seem to figure it out.

I sincerely appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and see if it works:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!5:5"),INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!2:2"),">="&B1,INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!2:2"),"<="&C1)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I added the name of the tab to A1 and when I change it to other tab names the summary changes accordingly.  Thanks so much tevlyn!  Much appreciated!!!